# Cannot send requests while disconnected

Tags: python, connection, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to connect account to `telethon` to collect messages from different channels.

If I use

```
with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash, system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM") as client:
    ...
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=list_channels))  # all channels id
    async def normal_handler(event):
        ...
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

then everything works well.But if I create an `Account` class (i need to connect 2 accounts later), then it raises `ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected` on `self.client.run_until_disconnected()`

my class:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, acc):
        self.client = TelegramClient(acc['name'], acc['api_id'], acc['api_hash'])
        self.client.run_until_disconnected()

    def run(self):
        @self.client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=list_channels))  # all channels id
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            ...
```

Comment: Note that the second approach won't exactly work, as `run` needs to execute before `__init__` for the handlers to be registered. A different approach should be used. However, the currently-accepted answer remains correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start/connect the client before using run_until_disconnected().

```py
self.client = TelegramClient(...).start()
```

Comment: FWIW, `start()` in Telethon v1 is a combination of `connect`, `is_user_authorized`, and if needed, `sign_in`. `with` also uses `start()`. So if you don't need the interactive flow, use *only* `connect` instead and login if you need to, however you need to.