# Python telethon login telegram from my website

Tags: python, django, telegram, telethon

Hi friends I write template in Django.User enter phone number and my telethon code sending code after  user enter code new input. I want to that user login in own telegram account. But this code not working.

1 STEP:
`phone_number = 'user number'`

`client = TelegramClient('session_name',`
`api_id,`
`api_hash)`
`phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone_number).phone_code_hash`
`client.connect()`
`f not client.is_user_authorized():`
`client.send_code_request(phone_number)`

2 STEP

`user = client.sign_in(phone_number,'89065')`

give error **ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected**

User login with telethon in Django. But I cant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot send requests while disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473507/cannot-send-requests-while-disconnected)